# Extract duplicity without rearranging the column and find cumsum in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cumsum, duplicity

I have a dataset with 4000 rows, where I have the duplicate rows(e.g. 2, 3, 4 times). I want to find the cumsum of the duplicates over time.

I have used this code to assign the number of duplicity. But it has rearranged the position of ID

```
df = duplicate_df.value_counts(sort=False, dropna=False).reset_index(name="Duplicity")
```

Output

```
ID       Time      Duplicity 
12345    2020        2
12345    2020        2
34567    2021        1
34696    2020        3  
34696    2020        3
34696    2020        3
```

whereas I want to add the duplicity and the ID remains same position.

```
ID       Time      Duplicity 
34696    2020        3  
12345    2020        2
12345    2020        2
34696    2020        3
34696    2020        3
34567    2021        1
```

How to find cumsum of duplicity over time? Thank you.

Input data:

```
d = {'ID': [34696, 12345, 12345, 34696, 34696, 34567],
     'Time': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021]}
```

Comment: are you sure you want the cumsum? looks like you just want to count how often each row appears.

Comment: Thank you for noting the point. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I want to find a visualization where it is showing how the duplicity reflect over time. In same month, some data reflects twice and thrice. How to visualize then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['Duplicity'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Time'])['ID'].transform('size')
print(df)

# Output
      ID  Time  Duplicity
0  34696  2020          3
1  12345  2020          2
2  12345  2020          2
3  34696  2020          3
4  34696  2020          3
5  34567  2021          1
```

Comment: This is clearly not the "cumsum of the duplicates over time" OP claims to want, but produces the correct result apparently.

Comment: @timgeb. I'm totally agree with you. I let the OP clarify this point.